# Does AjaxControl toolkit output modified MS AJAX Script

Tags: telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit, radwindow

I am currently using Telerik RadWindow control in my project which also uses controls from AjaxControlToolkit.  When AjaxScriptManager is added on the page RadWindow will misbehave by calling onclose event handler of RadWindow multiple for # of open RadWindow when RadWindow is closed and the remaining openned RadWinows will loose their onclose event handler.  The Telerik support person that responded to my issue indicated that the issue lies with AjaxControlToolkit for outputting mocidfed MS AJAX script and that Telerik controls will work correctly with the "proper" MS AJAX scripts.

I'm just curious. Does anyone know if AjaxControlToolkit injects/modified Microsoft ASP.Net AJAX script library?

Comment: What happens when you try ToolkitScriptManager?

Comment: The above scenario happens when ToolkitScriptManager is present in the page.  If it is replaced with ScriptManager or RadScriptManager then RadWindow works as expected. Since we use some controls from AjaxControlToolkit, removing ToolkitScriptManager will probably cause those controls not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. I've had the same issue with the events of RadWindow being broken by AjaxControlToolkit.